# Not all changes in subscribed docs are loaded

Tags: mongodb, meteor, publish-subscribe, subscription

I have such a method in my Meteor app:

```
addLocation: (location, tid) => {
  location = LocationSchema.clean(location);
  LocationSchema.validate(location);
  var lid = Locations.insert(location);
  Thoughts.update({_id: tid}, {$push: {locations: lid}});
}
```

I subscribe both `Locations` and `Thoughts` collections. But unfortunately after calling my method only changes in `Locations` collection are visible - my modified thought is still the same and I must reload page to see its changes. Is it bug in Meteor or my mistake? Do you know some ways to solve or bypass this problem?

What's more, when I push some value to `locations` array in some thought with Robomongo, changes are visible though. It looks like the problem is that two changes try to be seen at the same time.

Comment: Could you share the publish and subscribe code as well

Comment: Also make sure in your `Thoughts` publish function, you [return a cursor instead of an array](https://docs.meteor.com/api/pubsub.html#mongo_cursor).